# Is there any way to find current location after Pressing dont allow button of alert view in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an app in which i have to detect location after pressing Dont allow button which is present in starting alertview. I am explaing this in steps:

1. First step is comes splash screen with alert view having two buttons Don't Allow and oK.
2. Second is when user pressed Dont allow then second screen comes with detect location with two button on and off. when ok  is pressed , main screen comes after detecting location.
3. third is when on is pressed, Cllocation class allow to detect location.

But now i am confused about when i pressed the dont allow button in starting then how to possible detect again.

please give me some suggestions about CLLocation class or any other method to find user location.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can find user location as follows:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

You will need to add the CoreLocation framework and you can use the delegates below to see when a location update was made or if you were unable to find a location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation ;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, these method are well known but i am asking about when i pressed dont allow and after that i want again to allow current location then what method should i use?